# Mutual Authentication in ActiveMQ Artemis cluster fails to get hostname from client IP address

Tags: activemq-artemis, mutual-authentication, mtls

I have set up an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster (version 2.27.1)  to use mutual authentication. When the second node tries to connect to the first one, I get an error

```
WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222208: SSL handshake failed for client from /10.226.95.134:46882: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 10.226.95.134 found.
```

The hostname of the client is in the SAN of the certificate in the truststore.  I can't figure out how to configure the acceptor to use the hostname instead of the IP address.

The broker.xml configuration is

```xml
<acceptor name="netty-master-acceptor01">
tcp://dev-artemis01:61617?sslEnabled=true;needClientAuth=true;verifyHost=true;keyStorePath=/keys/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=123;trustStorePath=/keys/trusted_keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=password;protocols=CORE,AMQP
</acceptor>

...

<connector name="netty-master-connector02">
tcp://artemis02:61617?sslEnabled=true;keyStorePath=/keys/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=123;trustStorePath=/keys/trusted_keystore.jks;trustStorePassword=password
</connector>
```

I ran openssl commands between artemis01 and artemis02 servers and they worked

```
openssl s_server -accept 3000 -key dev_artemis.key -cert dev-artemis.pem -CAfile dev-artemis.pem -state

openssl s_client -connect dev-artemis01:3000 -key dev_artemis.key -cert dev-artemis.pem -CAfile dev-artemis.pem -state
```

How can I configure the `acceptor` to use hostnames (which are in the SAN) instead of the raw IP addresses?

**Edit**: 
This is what keytool shows in the certificate

```
keytool -list  -v -storepass 123 -keystore keystore-dev-artemisrr.jks
```

```
Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: dev-artemisrr
Creation date: Jul 13, 2023
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=dev-artemisrr, OU=cfrm, O="Example Technologies, Inc.", L=Portsmouth, ST=New Hampshire, C=US
Issuer: CN=dev-artemisrr, OU=cfrm, O="Example Technologies, Inc.", L=Portsmouth, ST=New Hampshire, C=US
Serial number: 88da32c
Valid from: Thu Jul 13 15:55:28 EDT 2023 until: Sun Jul 12 15:55:28 EDT 2026
Certificate fingerprints:
     SHA1: 73:50:59:55:2B:18:F1:32:E2:DA:FA:C0:C1:C6:5A:F2:14:3F:91:D8
     SHA256: 09:36:4C:59:63:45:5B:72:59:54:2A:83:48:74:43:F0:63:D5:A3:42:DB:35:E5:C6:E5:33:D8:2B:A4:85:37:3A
Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
Subject Public Key Algorithm: 2048-bit RSA key
Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr01-blue
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr02-blue
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr03-blue
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr01-green
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr02-green
  DNSName: dev-artemisrr03-green
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F8 7C 9C 65 AF FF 8F B6   BA 3E A0 26 46 C7 1C AA  ...e.....>.&F...
0010: F3 C9 43 9F                                        ..C.
]
]

*******************************************
*******************************************
```

I used the following script to create the certificate

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create Artemis Cluster Certificate.  

set -e

function createSAN()
{
    env=$1
    num_servers=$2
    server_type=$3
    alias_server_type="$server_type"0
    
    san="SAN="

    for ((i=0; i < $num_servers; i++)); 
    do
        san+="DNS:$env-$alias_server_type$((i+1))-blue,"
    done
    
    for ((i=0; i < $num_servers; i++)); 
    do
        san+="DNS:$env-$alias_server_type$((i+1))-green,"
    done

    # truncate the last comma
    san=${san%?}
    
    echo $san
}

function createCertificate()
{
    env=$1
    num_servers=$2
    server_type=$3

    echo -e "\nCreating $server_type certificate..."
    
    createSAN $env $num_servers $server_type
    
    # Create the certificate
    cn=$env-$server_type
    keytool -keystore keystore-$env-$server_type.jks -keyalg RSA -genkey -alias $env-$server_type -ext "$san" -dname "CN=$cn,OU=engineering,O=Ajax Technologies\, Inc.,L=Portsmouth,ST=New Hampshire,C=US" -validity 1095 -storepass $password -keypass $password
    
    # convert to pkcs12
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore-$env-$server_type.jks -destkeystore keystore-$env-$server_type.p12 -deststoretype pkcs12 -deststorepass $password -srcstorepass $password
    
    # Extract the SSL certificate 
    openssl pkcs12 -nokeys -chain -in keystore-$env-$server_type.p12 -out $env-$server_type.crt -password pass:$password 
    
    # Extract the key
    openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -in keystore-$env-$server_type.p12 -out $env-$server_type.key -password pass:$password
    
    # Remove the bag attributes to be loaded into trusted keystore
    openssl x509 -in $env-$server_type.crt -out $env-$server_type.pem   
}

function createTrustedKeystore()
{
    # keytool -import -file C:\cacerts\firstCA.cert -alias firstCA -keystore myTrustStore
    for file in *.pem; do
        alias="$(basename "$file" | cut -d '.' -f1)"
        keytool -import -noprompt -file $alias.pem -alias $alias -keystore trusted_keystore.jks -storepass password
    done

}

rm -f *.jks *.p12 *.crt *.key

password=secret
createCertificate dev 3 artemis

password=password
createTrustedKeystore
```

I modified the configurations a little to remove some private information and uploaded the files in the etc folder to https://gist.github.com/milindrao/935f86f30a6f921da915ed44d17e4f1a

What's making this even more difficult to debug is that setting -Djavax.net.debug=all in the artemis.profile file is not spitting out any SSL logs in the artemis.log file.  In fact, modifying the log4j2.properties file to add ssl logging won't even allow the artemis service to start.

```
logger.handshake.name=javax.net.ssl
logger.handshake.level=DEBUG
```

Comment: not programming or development, but: `openssl` doesn't tell you anything useful here. `s_client` by default doesn't check the identity in a server cert, and `s_server` by default doesn't even request/obtain a client cert; if you specify `-verify` or `-Verify` to do client auth, it doesn't check the identity. (`s_client` always, and `s_server` with `-[vV]erify`, does check that the cert validates per RFC5280 except for revocation: chains to a trusted root with valid signatures, time within validity period, extensions like basicconstraints and keyusage correct, etc.)

Comment: Any chance you could work up steps to reproduce your configuration including the SSL certs (e.g. using Java's `keytool`)?

Comment: @JustinBertram I added the keytool certificate output to the description.  We use puppet to provision and install Artemis.  If there's anything else in the configuration that you'd like to see, please let me know.  I don't see anything else in the broker.xml that relates to ssl

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  Yes.  I realize that openssl doesn't seem to be checking the certificates or hostnams.  Using the documentation on https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-verification-options.html, I used the -verify_hostname parameter, but it doesn't really check anything.  If I pass garbage in the hostname, it doesn't spit out any errors

Comment: I was thinking more of the commands required to _create_ the SSL certs as well as the cluster-related configuration so I could reproduce this error myself. Keep in mind that ActiveMQ Artemis delegates all SSL handshaking to the JVM (or potentially to OpenSSL, depending on the configuration) so there may not being anything the broker can do about this.

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks so much for taking the time.  I have added the script to create the certificate and the configuration to gist.  I should note that similar configuration is working in an earlier version of Artemis.  But I just can't find the (probably incorrect) configuration which is causing the problem.

Comment: In what version was it working? Have you tried the latest release (i.e. 2.30.0)?

Comment: @JustinBertram I was mistaken about it working on earlier version (2.16.0).  A look at the trusted keystores in that deployment shows the SAN contains IP addresses!  Running the command from the CLI rather than starting the service, got me the stack trace that helped me figure out where this is happening.  The HostnameChecker.verify method is matching the IP because the server is sending the IP address.  That's happening in X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity method, which is getting the IP address from the socket.getPeerHost method.  It doesn't even attempt to check the certificate.

Comment: Is that happening in the JVM's code or the broker's code?

Comment: This is all in the JVM code.  I tried this on OpenJDK 1.8, 17 and 20.  Same behavior in all except slightly different code.  The X509TrustManagerImpl class is bypassing the certificate and simply getting the host from the socket which is always an IP address.
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/X509TrustManagerImpl.java#L416